# JavaScript concating with number as string

Tags: javascript, string, syntax, operators, concatenation

Why does `x = "1"- -"1"` work and set the value of `x` to `2`?

Why doesn't `x = "1"--"1"` works?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This expression...

```
"1"- -"1"
```

... is processed as ...

```
"1"- (-"1")
```

... that is, substract result of unary minus operation applied to "1" from "1". Now, both unary and binary minus operations make sense to be applied for Numbers only - so JS converts its operands to Numbers first. So that'll essentially becomes:

```
Number("1") - (-(Number("1"))
```

... that'll eventually becomes evaluated to 2, as `Number("1")`, as you probably expect, evaluates to `1`.

---

When trying to understand `"1"--"1"` expression, JS parser attempts to consume as many characters as possible. That's why this expression `"1"--` is processed first.

But it makes no sense, as auto-increment/decrement operations are not defined for literals. Both `++` and `--` (both in postfix and prefix forms) should change the value of some assignable ('left-value') expression - variable name, object property etc.

In this case, however, there's nothing to change: "1" literal is *always* "1". )

---

Actually, I got a bit different errors (for x = "1"--"1") both in Firefox:

```
SyntaxError: invalid decrement operand
```

... and Chrome Canary:

```
ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation
```

And I think these messages actually show the reason of that error quite clearly. )

Answer (score 2):

Because `--` is an operator in JavaScript.

When you separate the `-` characters in the first expression, it's unambiguous what you mean.  When you put them together, JavaScript interprets them as one operator, and the following `"1"` as an unexpected string. (Or maybe it's the *preceding* `"1"`? I'm honestly not sure.)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#--_.28Decrement.29

Comment: Actually, it's still unambiguous for JS even with "1"--"1" - that's always treated as ("1"--)"1". So yes, if `"1"--` expression were valid, `"1"` should have been treated as unexpected string. )

Comment: @raina77ow "1"--"1" is unambiguous to JavaScript, but I can interpret it in two different ways. The way that the OP meant, and the way JavaScript interprets it.

Answer (score 0):

"-1" = -1 (unary minus converts it to int)
So. "1" - (-1)
now, "+" is thje concatenation operator. not -. so JS returns the result 2 (instead of string concat).

also, "1"--"1" => here "--" is the decrement operator, for which the syntax is wrong as strings will not get converted automatically in this case.

Answer (score 0):

because `--` is an operator for decrement and cannot be applied on constant values.